# Redirect with mod_rewrite inside a wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently, the wordpress installation uses urls such as:
http://example.com/test-page

It uses the 'test-page' part of the URL to look up which page to display. My problem is I built a custom application that is being loaded into wordpress via a PHP include plugin. This application relies on URLs such as
http://examples.com/test-page/title-of-page/id

I need to use mod_rewrite to make this go to:
http://example.com/test-page&title=$1&id=$2 (since test page itself is part of the query string)

I have tried a multitude of things, searching SO, reading about mod_rewrite flags and testing out different regex solutions.

Here is one of my attempts:

```
RewriteRule ^directory-listing/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /directory-listing&title=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^directory-listing/([^/]+) /directory-listing&title=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^directory-listing$ /directory-listing [L]
```

Entire .htaccess as of right now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

## Custom ##
RewriteRule ^directory-listing/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /directory-listing&title=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^directory-listing/([^/]+) /directory-listing&title=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^directory-listing$ /directory-listing [L]
## End Custom ##

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
#RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I am genuinely stuck. I really need some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I was heavily lacking in understanding how wordpress handles redirects. After some further research, I found that I actually needed to add hooks into the functions.php file in order to get this to work as I expect. I added these to the bottom of the file and was able to accomplish what I was trying to do.

```
function rewrite_tags_for_directory_listings() { 
    add_rewrite_tag('%dir_title%', '([^/]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%dir_id%', '([^/]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'rewrite_tags_for_directory_listings', 10, 0);

function rewrite_rule_for_directory_listings() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^directory-listing/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$','index.php?page_id=11794&dir_title=$matches[1]&dir_id=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'rewrite_rule_for_directory_listings', 10, 0);
```

Then, in my included PHP file, I got the variables as such:

```
global $wp_query;
$id = $wp_query->query_vars['dir_id'];
```